# Is this the inspiration for the music used in Dredd?

Tags: soundtrack, dredd, sound-effects

In the *Dredd* film when they show the effects of the Slo-Mo drug. There is this dramatic sound track that represents the effects of the drug.

I found a YouTube video of a very similar (if not the same) sound track dating back to 2010. Can anyone confirm if this was the inspiration for the sound track in the film?

I found the none-slowed version of this sound. This is funny how the two are so different.

Finally, here is a reference from Dredd with the Slo-Mo drug music playing in the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Paul Leonard-Morgan wrote the film's industrial music score.
>   Leonard-Morgan created music to suit the film's futuristic setting. He
>   experimented with band-based music, but decided it sounded
>   over-produced and too safe. He turned to electronic music and used
>   1980s-style synthesisers and modern sound modules to create various
>   combinations and applied distortion and other effects to the result.
>   Leonard-Morgan said, "I was looking to create a timeless score which
>   couldn't be placed in any particular era. So it's ended up being a
>   cross between a modern dance track and evocative soundscapes." For
>   scenes conveying the effect of the Slo-Mo narcotic, he composed new
>   music with real instruments and then slowed the songs down by
>   thousands of percent to match the visuals, such that one second of his
>   composed score could last 10 minutes. He then added additional
>   real-time score to the slowed track. An unofficially altered
>   Justin Bieber song served as inspiration for the Slo-Mo theme. Garland
>   said that Portishead instrumentalist Geoff Barrow "sent me a link to a
>   Justin Bieber song slowed down 800 times and it became this stunning
>   trippy choral music." Morgan then recreated the effect based on the
>   modified track, which was used in the finished film. The film used
>   Bieber's music as a temporary placeholder during editing before the
>   score was finalized.[(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dredd#Music)

**From the above wiki reference**-
Garland
 said that Portishead instrumentalist Geoff Barrow "sent me a link to a
 Justin Bieber song slowed down 800 times and it became this stunning
 trippy choral music. That clearly says that its inspired from Biber song and even it is temporary placeholder during editing before the
 score was finalized.

Comment: I'd give you +10 if I could for saving this movie from having a Justin Beaver song in it.

Answer (score 5):

The slow-mo music was apparently based on a slowed down [Justin Bieber song](http://metronews.ca/scene/374978/dredd-3d-might-make-you-a-belieber/), but I seem to recall slowing songs like this was a popular fad a few years ago.

Comment: Got any references?

Comment: Well, there's the article I linked to.

Comment: I think what Tyler meant was references from people who made the movie not just ones who watches it

Comment: That and I didn't even see that browsing from mobile last night.  Apologies

Comment: @Dredd - The article is quoting Alex Garland, the film's writer. I can't find any other references, though, which does seem a tiny bit suspicious.

-TylerShads - No problem. I wasn't actually sure if I was able to post links, so I was a little worried it might not have shown up for you.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!! This can't be true! I refuse to accept this answer on the grounds that Justin Bieber should NOT be in the Dredd film!